# CURL '&&' operator alternatives

Tags: curl

what is alternative for '&&' operator in CURL. windows command prompt take && as reserved keywords so it fails the running task. i need to replace && with something else. ';'semi-colon works but it breaks the && operator condition. Can anybody suggest me something else

Comment: You mean to run curl and if it succeed run another command?

Comment: this is a part of CURL command --\"ASSOCIATED_PARTIES\":\"('${#first_name}'.equals('AAA'))&&('${#last_name}'.equals('AAA'))&&('${#first_name}'.equals('BBB')) i need to replace && from this command with somthing but it should work in script aswell

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).